# Convert System.Drawing.Image resource into System.Windows.Controls.Image for wpf MenuItem

Tags: wpf

I've got resources in my assembly which I can Access using Properties.Resources.MyImage.
And I have some class which I bind to a WPF MenuItem containing a property

```
public System.Windows.Controls.Image Icon {get; set;}
```

This I want to set programmatically using:

```
dummy.Icon = Properties.Resources.MyImage;
```

Now I want to convert the resource System.Drawing.Image to the WPF System.Windows.Controls.Image. I thought this should be straightforward, but I found no working solution for my Images (which are png files using transparency).

So how do I convert System.Drawing.Image into System.Windows.Controls.Image?

Comment: Good hint, but how? I can't bind directly in xaml to the resource, it needs to be set at runtime. So how do I Access the resource from code in replacement to using Properties.Resources.MyImage?

Comment: Is there a replacement which can be used with WPF? As I said, I Need to set it from the code, not in xaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Properties.Resources`, which are Windows Forms Embedded Resources, use WPF resources. In Solution Explorer, click the image file and in the properties window, set its Build Action to **Resource** (*not* Embedded Resource). This also embeds the image into the assembly, but in a different way.

Unlike Windows Forms, WPF does not generate a resource manager class, so you'd have to use strings to load the images dynamically:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/NameOfAssembly;component/Path/To/Image.png");
image.EndInit();
```

Note the `application` and `component` parts of the URI are constant strings, while `NameOfAssemly` is the name of the assembly where the image is in. You can build a helper class that builds the URI and loads images.

You can also call `image.Freeze()` if you don't plan on making any changes to the image (improves performance and allows image source to be created on non-UI threads).

In your data class, expose an `ImageSource` property instead of an `Image`. Then you use the `Image` control to display it:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
```

Or inside a style:

```
<Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="Icon"
                x:Shared="False"
                Source="{Binding Icon}"
                Width="16"
                Height="16" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource Icon}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: So I need to create my own resource manager class - well, seems to be the better way. I'll check this out and mark as answer when I get it to work, thanks!!